# Unir distintos csv en uno con python

Tags: python

Tengo distintos archivos csv y todos tienen escrito solo la primera columna. Entonces he querido unir todos estos csv en uno solo, pero lo que consigo es añadir siempre la información en la misma columna y yo lo que quiero es 'meter' cada csv en una columna distinta de un mismo archivo.
¿Hay alguna forma?

Comment: Tienes que publicar el código que tengas hasta el momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El siguiente código te permite unir una cantidad ilimitada de archivos .csv de entrada y producir un archivo .csv de salida.

El código toma los headers de cada .csv de entrada para formar el header del archivo de salida.

Para facilitar el uso, definimos una función `junta_csv` que recibe el nombre del archivo de salida y una lista conteniendo los nombres de los archivos de entrada.

```
def junta_csv(salida, archivos):
    """
    Crea un archivo .csv a partir de multiples
    archivos .csv con una sola columna

    :param salida: Nombre del archivo de salida.
    :param archivos: Lista de archivos de entrada.
                     Son .csv con header en la primera fila.
    """
    handles = [] # Archivos de entrada
    headers = [] # Headers de cada archivo de entrada
    #
    #   Abrir los archivos de entradas, leer los headers
    #
    for arch in archivos:
        file_handle = open(arch, "r")
        handles.append(file_handle)
        headers.append(file_handle.readline().strip())

    with open(salida, "w") as out:
        #   Formar la primera linea con los headers de
        #   las columnas.
        header = ",".join(headers)
        out.write(f"{header}\n")

        eof = False
        while not eof:
            fila = []
            #   Leer una fila de cada archivo para
            #   formar una fila de salida.
            for handle in handles:
                dato = handle.readline()
                if dato:
                    fila.append(dato.strip())
                else:
                    eof = True
                    break

            if not eof:
                #   Grabar la fila de salida.
                salida = ','.join(fila)
                out.write(f"{salida}\n")

    #   Cerrar tosdos los archivos
    out.close()
    for handle in handles:
        handle.close()
```

**Demo**

arch1.csv

```
Sequencia
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

arch2.csv

```
Valor
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

*Código*

```
archivos = ["arch1.csv", "arch2.csv"]
junta_csv("salida.csv", archivos)
```

produce:

salida.csv

```
Sequencia,Valor
1,11
2,12
3,13
4,14
5,15
6,16
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha servido genial! Era justo lo que buscaba

Comment: Quería comentar una cosa.Mis columnas no son uniformes. Es decir una columna puede tener 20 elementos y otra 50, sin embargo cuando ejecuto el código y me une las columnas toma el menor valor común entre todas las columnas. En el caso que te acabo de poner, solo me une los 20 primeros elementos, y los otros 30 restantes desaparecen. ¿Hay alguna solución?

Comment: El supuesto implícito es que todas las columnas son de igual largo. Si hay distintos largos, sería necesario declarar un valor por default para completar cada fila. Plantea una nueva pregunta "¿Cómo unir .csv de distinto largo?" y explica como quieres llenar lo que falta (con ceros, espacios, el último valor disponible, etc.)

Comment: Vale de acuerdo, es que ando perdido con los archivos csv... Voy a formular otra pregunta

Comment: Cómo puedo utilizar este codigo para unir archivos con mas de una columna?

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo usando la librería pandas. Primero necesitas extraer tus datos y guardarlo en variables

```
import pandas as pd
dt=pd.read_csv("primer.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("segundo.csv")
```

En caso de que haya más de una columna y debas elegir, la seleccionas así

```
nu=dt["Id"]
nonu=df["Id"]
```

Después generas el dataframe

```
data ={'primera': nu,'segunda':nonu}
defu = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['primera','segunda'])
defu
```

En donde defu es tu tabla ya con las columnas de los archivos. Suerte